# Extracting Data from Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, amazon-s3

I'm working with the S3 library found here: http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/

It works great, but I'm having a tough time extracting the data I need from the returned array results. I'm grabbing the bucket contents, and it returns something like this:

```
Array (
   [sample_mpeg4.mp4] => Array (
        [name] => sample_mpeg4.mp4
        [time] => 1378922417
        [size] => 245779
        [hash] => dc77a8de8c091c19d86df74eb7
   )
   [steve.jpg] => Array (
        [name] => steve.jpg
        [time] => 1381270899
        [size] => 61109
        [hash] => a008368bf58515775c45e75c54
   )
   [stev-small-photo1.png] => Array (
        [name] => stev-small-photo1.png
        [time] => 1381270891
        [size] => 680353
        [hash] => ddcb22a103d4fa8360083ad70a
   )
)
```

Ok, cool. I'm querying and matching the key to pull out specific info on that particular piece of media. My code for that looks like this:

```
        $searchVar = "steve.jpg";

        $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey); 
        $bucket_contents = $s3->getBucket("uploads.bucket.com");  

    //fetch array of current files
        $searchAssetsBucket = array_keys($bucket_contents);

        foreach ($searchAssetsBucket as $value) {
            if($value == $searchVar) {
                echo $value['time'];
            }   
        }

        if(empty($returnValue)) {
            $returnValue = "Sorry no results for <b>$searchVar</b>.";
        }
```

This doesn't work for me. What I'm really trying to do is get the code to return the name/time/size/hash vars from the [steve.jpg] array once it's been matched. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but this code simply returns "s".

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm truly at a lose here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$myArray=$yourOriginalS3Array;
$searchVar='Steve.jpg';

// set up default/blank data in $matchedArr
foreach ($myArray as $key => $val) 
{
    if($key == $searchVar) {
    $matchedArr=$val;
    }
}

echo "The name is ".$matchedArr['name']." and the size is ".$matchedArr['size']."<br>";
```

This way, you are checking the keys of your original array, and if matched, returning an array that matches the second level of the original array which can be easily accessed in your code.